# How can I boot my MBP into normal mode despite shift key being broken (and on)?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, damage

I recently went to the Apple store with my laptop because it would only boot into safe mode and would not accept my password. While there, they said some liquid ruined something in the inside of my laptop. They said that the shift key was internally broken and will cost up to $700 to fix. Now, in order to use my laptop, I need to use an external USB keyboard.

But, whenever I turn my laptop on, it boots into Safe mode. Is there a way to disable it? I have tried holding down <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd> but nothing has worked for me. Does anyone have anysuggestions?

Comment: Have you tried physically removing the shift key, to see what's under it?

Comment: What model of Mac? Did you inquire with the tech about the possibility that the keyboard could be totally disconnected to allow you to use an external keyboard without the damaged circuits and switches from interfering with the computer?

Comment: Related questions: [36636](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36636/how-can-i-disable-safe-boot-or-the-shift-key), [75318](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75318/can-a-mac-boot-when-the-right-shift-key-is-broken-in-the-pressed-position), [25325](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25325/ideas-for-reinstalling-mac-os-x-on-a-2009-macbook-pro-whose-shift-key-is-constan)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try holding the option key through the power-on?  On my MacBook Pro, the combination of option + shift seems to boot normally; while, just shift goes to safe mode as expected.