# How to do a clean OS X 10.11 reinstall when shift key stuck

Tags: macos, startup

My left shift key is stuck down (wiring-wise, not just mechanically stuck) - fine, I changed my password to be all caps and once I'm logged in I use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) to disable the key, and because my left pinky muscle memory still thinks there's a shift key over there, I've got a plastic lever that depresses my left control key when I go for the shift key and have that remapped to shift.

[image]

Yesterday I had to upgrade from OS X 10.9 to install Xcode without a developer account. But I wasn't paying attention - now there's an even new operating system, OS X 10.11, which I accidentally installed instead!

I'd ideally like to do a clean install of OS X 10.10, or at least a clean installation of OSX 10.11 instead of the migrated one I have now. How install either of these with a stuck shift key?

- I can't use any [startup key combinations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) besides safe mode, and normal mode by holding another key during startup
- The system preferences "Startup Disk" panel doesn't show a recovery partition, netboot, or a bootable USB stick that I made with `createinstallmedia` (though I believe the recovery partition exists)

Similar question from 2011: [Ideas for reinstalling Mac OS X on a 2009 Macbook Pro whose shift key is constantly stuck down?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25325/ideas-for-reinstalling-mac-os-x-on-a-2009-macbook-pro-whose-shift-key-is-constan)

Comment: Replace your keyboard.

Comment: If you turn on caps lock, the behavior of the shift key is inverted. Perhaps that will help